# Getting type string after converting to JSON in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

Trying to convert string to JSON in PowerShell.

```bsh
$resultsTable = $webresults.Content
Write-Host $resultsTable
```

Output:

```
{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"ComputerIP","type":"string"}],"rows":[["40.121.111.160"],["104.41.134.153"]]}]}
```

but still getting `System.String`

```bsh
$resultsTable = $webresults.Content | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host $resultsTable
Write-Host $resultsTable.GetType()
```

Output:

```
"{\"tables\":[{\"name\":\"PrimaryResult\",\"columns\":[{\"name\":\"ComputerIP\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"rows\":[[\"40.121.111.160\"],[\"104.41.134.153\"]]}]}"
System.String
```

Comment: The String is json so you should be converting From not To, use the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Trying to convert string to json in Powershell

As has been [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900348/getting-type-string-after-converting-to-json-in-powershell#comment104064655_58900348): your string is *already* a json document.

If you want to convert it to some structured objects you can work with, you'll have to use `ConvertFrom-Json`:

```
PS C:\> $object = $resultsTable |ConvertFrom-Json
PS C:\> $object.GetType().Name
PSCustomObject
PS C:\> $object |Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
tables      NoteProperty Object[] tables=System.Object[]
```